# Regex for Python Needed

Tags: python, regex

Here are my strings :

```
-rwxrwx--- Administrators/unknown      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log

-rwxrwx--- kandep2/Domain Users      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log
```

I would like to capture everything in a group except 0%.
So far, i have the following regex:

```
([rwexXst-]+) ([^1-9]+) +(\d+)+.+? +(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.*)
```

This works for the first row, but it fails on the second row because second row username has a number in it.

How should i modify my regex to get output like this:

Group#1

```
-rwxrwx---
Administrators/unknown
563092
2018-05-29 02:16:49
E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log
```

Group #2

```
-rwxrwx---
kandep2/Domain Users 
563092
2018-05-29 02:16:49
E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups). Also, try and generalize your regex so you don't have to count exact spaces.

Try:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'''(?P<rw>[rwexXst\-]+)\s+
(?P<dir>\w+(?:\s+\w+)?\/\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)\s+
(?P<nums>\d+)(?:.+\%)?\s+
(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+
(?P<msg>.*)$''', flags=re.M|re.X)

test_text = '''
-rwxrwx--- Administrators/unknown      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log

-rwxrwx--- kandep2/Domain Users      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log
'''

for i in re.finditer(test_text):
    match = re.search(i)
    if match:
        print(match.groupdict())
        print(match.groups())
```

Or the even simpler:

```
for match in pattern.finditer(test_text):
    print(match.groupdict())
    print(match.groups())
```

Should give you:

```
{'rw': '-rwxrwx---', 
 'dir': 'Administrators/unknown', 
 'nums': '563092', 
 'date': '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 
 'msg': 'E:/program files/backup agents for cluster groups/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log'}
('-rwxrwx---', 
 'Administrators/unknown', 
 '563092', 
 '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 
 'E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log')
{'rw': '-rwxrwx---', 
 'dir': 'kandep2/Domain Users', 
 'nums': '563092', 
 'date': '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 
 'msg': 'E:/program files/backup agents for cluster groups/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log'}
('-rwxrwx---', 
 'kandep2/Domain Users', 
 '563092', '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 
 'E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log')
```

Comment: Great!! what if i don't want dict style output but single units?

Comment: @PetPan a regex match object has several choices for extracting the result, including by order with the `match.groups()` method.

Comment: what would be one line regex to get all groups? if i don't want dict style output?

Comment: @PetPan its listed in my previous comment: `match_variable.groups()`

Comment: @PetPan cleaned up a mistake in the pattern and added a simpler way to extract the data as well as added the `.groups()` we discussed in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You could use a verbose expression with named capturing groups like so:

```
(?P<rights>-[-rwx]+)\s+         # rights -> one of -,r,w,x
(?P<group>(?:(?!\s{2,}).)+)\s+  # anything not two consecutive whitespaces
(?P<uid>\d+)\s+                 # only digits
(?:[\d%]+)\s+                   # digits and %
(?P<date>[- :\d]+)\s+           # the date
(?P<filename>.+)                # and the filename
```

---

In `Python` this is:

```
import re

data = """
-rwxrwx--- Administrators/unknown      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log

-rwxrwx--- kandep2/Domain Users      563092   0% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?P<rights>-[-rwx]+)\s+
    (?P<group>(?:(?!\s{2,}).)+)\s+
    (?P<uid>\d+)\s+
    (?:[\d%]+)\s+
    (?P<date>[- :\d]+)\s+
    (?P<filename>.+)''', re.M | re.X)

results = [m.groupdict() for m in rx.finditer(data)]
print(results)
```

This will yield

```
[
    {'rights': '-rwxrwx---', 'group': 'Administrators/unknown', 'uid': '563092', 'date': '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 'filename': 'E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/work.log'}, 
    {'rights': '-rwxrwx---', 'group': 'kandep2/Domain Users', 'uid': '563092', 'date': '2018-05-29 02:16:49', 'filename': 'E:/program files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log'}
]
```

---

The idea is to capture anything of interest and to match (or use non-capturing groups) for the "garbage". See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FdKPMD/1).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution without regex.**

```
from pprint import pprint

input_row = '-rwxrwx--- kandep2/Domain %Users      563092   0%% 2018-05-29 02:16:49 E:/program $files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log'


def parse(value):
    v = value.index(':/')

    row = input_row[:v-1].strip()
    row = row.split()

    return {
        'rw': row.pop(0),
        'date': '%s %s' % (row.pop(-2), row.pop(-1)),
        'value': row.pop(-1),
        'nums': row.pop(-1),
        'msg': input_row[v-1:],
        'dir': ' '.join(row),
    }


pprint(parse(input_row))
```

**Result:**

```
{'date': '2018-05-29 02:16:49',
 'dir': 'kandep2/Domain %Users',
 'msg': 'E:/program $files/bak fil/sql server (mssqlserver)/var/dummy.log',
 'nums': '563092',
 'rw': '-rwxrwx---',
 'value': '0%%'}
```